# Configuring the Hyperledger Composer REST server with a persistent data store

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am following this tutorial 
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/deploying-the-rest-server.html

I have done all the steps. But when I run rest-server through github, it prints following stack trace.

**Error
404 Cannot GET /auth/github
status: 404
Error: Cannot GET /auth/github
    at raiseUrlNotFoundError (/home/praval/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/loopback/server/middleware/url-not-found.js:21:17)**

Answer (score 0):

I presume you installed the Github strategy via npm install -g passport-github?

If so did it create a folder /auth/github?

You are required to go to this Folder per documentation:  "Authenticate to the REST server by navigating to the value of the authPath property specified in the environment variable COMPOSER_PROVIDERS. In the example above, this is http://localhost:3000/auth/github"

In my case that folder was not created. I read on Github website: https://github.com/cfsghost/passport-github
"The author of Passport-Github has not maintained the original module for a long time. Features in his module don't work since Github upgraded their API to version 3.0. We forked it and re-published it to NPM with a new name passport-github2"

I'm looking for guidance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Before create private api just execute this command in your terminal.

`export COMPOSER_PROVIDERS='{
  "github": {
    "provider": "github",
    "module": "passport-github",
    "clientID": "<your id>",
    "clientSecret": "<your secret>",
    "authPath": "/auth/github",
    "callbackURL": "/auth/github/callback",
    "successRedirect": "http://localhost(domain of angular app):4200(port)/home(page to redirect)",
    "failureRedirect": "http://localhost(domain of angular app):4200(port)/login-github(page to redirect)""
  }
}'`

To check if all is fine - run command

```
echo $COMPOSER_PROVIDERS
```

After this you will see your COMPOSER_PROVIDERS value.

And after in github profile app (https://github.com/settings/applications/) you must configure "**Homepage URL**" (ex. http://APIdomain:3000/) and "**Authorization callback URL**" (ex. http://APIdomain:3000/auth/github/callback)